# Cannot perform a basic find on a collection

Tags: mongodb

I understand this looks a silly question, but I'm failing to perform a basic find on a collection. From the docs I can read that this is the syntax for performing a find:

```
db.collection.find(<criteria>, <projection>)
```

So why the following find fails ?

```
> show databases;
admin          (empty)
local          0.078GB
m101           0.078GB
test           0.078GB


> use m101;
switched to db m101

> show collections;
funnynumbers
hw1
system.indexes

> m101.hw1.find();
2015-01-07T22:43:26.358+0100 ReferenceError: m101 is not defined
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: use **db.hw1.find();** not **m101.hw1.find();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below command. You no need to specify the database name again.

**> db.hw1.find();**

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood that "db" was to be replaced with the db name